# Will Modules work on Android after it is converted to Apk?

Tags: python, android, module, kivy, kivy-language

I am making an Android app with Python in Kivy in Mobile . Some modules doesn't support Android . So if I code in PC and after it is converted to APK will it work on Android ? Will the dependaries be installed? If no, is there any other way to use modules like cv2 , pyttsx3 , etc.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If the modules don't support android, then it won't be possible to run code built with it on Android.

Comment: Android does have a whole text to speech system built into the framework, and opencv does work on Android as a C library. So you can get the functionality, but you may need to write bindings and wrappers on your own.